# Could someone help me identify this bike?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I would much appreciate it if someone could help me identify this bike? The decals says Viner, but I think the bike is from a different manufacture.

Here are some images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check for a serial number on the head tube or bottom bracket or near the drop outs?

Comment: There is a serial number on the head tube, 9B04272. I am not a bike expert so it doesn't tell me much. Any ideas?

Comment: I would guess the bike is from the mid/late-80s.  Decent quality.

Comment: I bought the bike quite recently not knowing a lot about road bikes. Consequently done quite a bit of research since then and wondering what to do with it and whether it was a good investment due to the unknown frame.

Comment: The only measure of a bike being a good investment is if the happiness it brings you to ride it was worth the cost. If you need to know the original manufacturer in order to decide whether or not you're satisfied with the purchase (and you're not a collector or something), you're doing it wrong. Stop worrying about who built your bike and *go have fun riding it*.

Comment: Would've have liked to know the manufacture, but you are right. It has been a lot of fun having the bike though.

Comment: Looks like a beautiful bike! I love c&v and this definitely is an eye catcher. What is the component group? That can help narrow down years. Dia Compe engraved the manufacture date into the back of their brakes for example.

Comment: @StephenTouset the *only* measure? You're making this up, right? Plus, it's totally irrelevant as OP said nothing about value or investment.

Comment: Quoting the OP, "[I am] wondering what to do with it and whether it was a good investment due to the unknown frame". My point stands.

Answer (score 1):

They were an Italian manufacturer, I'm not sure if the branding has been resold since the 70's as there are new bikes now with the same name. 
They were used professionally and known for their lug ornamentation on some models.

There have been a few folks with similar questions here:
http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/175841-vintage-viner.html

Comment: Do you think it is a Viner though? I have only seen ones with star and cross shaped cutouts, never with the S.

Comment: I still see some very similar vintage bikes around here in Italy :)